# CodeIgniter Can not open view

Tags: codeigniter

I am just started with CodeIgniter and one interesting think is when I press button "Read More" i get error "404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found."
Just looking inside the code but cannot find any mistake
Any comment, help ?

Posts controller

```
 <?php


class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    public function index($page='home'){

        $data['title']= 'Sve voznje';

        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($mjesto_polaska=NULL){
        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjesto_polaska);
        if(empty($data['post'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = $data['mjesto_polaska'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function create(){
        $data['title'] ='Create Posts';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE){

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }else {
            $this->Posts_model->create_post();
            redirect('posts');
        }

    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->Posts_model->delete_post($id);
        redirect('posts');
    }
}
```

Posts Model

```
<?php
 class Posts_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_posts($mjesto_polaska=FALSE){
        if($mjesto_polaska === FALSE){
            $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
            $query=$this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts', array('mjesto_polaska' => $mjesto_polaska));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function create_post(){
        $mjesto_polaska=url_title($this->input->post('title'));

        $data=array(
                'mjesto_polaska'=>$mjesto_polaska,
                'mjesto_odredista'=>$this->input->post('mjesto_odredista'),
                'datum_polaska'=>$this->input->post('datum_polaska'),
                'datum_povratka'=>$this->input->post('datum_povratka'),
                'cijena'=>$this->input->post('cijena'),
                'broj_mjesta'=>$this->input->post('broj_mjesta'),
                'opis'=>$this->input->post('opis'),


        );
        return $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
    }

    public function delete_posts($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
        return true;
    }
 }
```

index.php

```
<h2><?= $title?></h2>
<?php foreach($posts as $post) :?>

<h3><?php echo  $post['mjesto_polaska']; ?></h3>
<small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?></small><br>
<br>
<p><a class="btn btn-default"    href="<?php echo site_url('/posts'.$post['mjesto_polaska']);?>">Read More</a></p>
<p><a class="btn btn-default"    href="<?php echo site_url('/posts'.$post['id']);?>">Delete</a></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

view.php

```
<h2><?php echo $posts['title'];?></h2>
<small class="post-date">Posted on:<?php echo post['created_at'];?></small>

<div class="post-body">
<?php echo $post['body'];?>
</div>

<hr>
<?php form_open('/posts/delete'.$post['id']);?>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

routes.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['posts/create']='posts/create';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
$route['posts']='posts/index/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Title has to change from `Can` to `Cannot`..

Comment: When you view source, what does the Read More link look like?

Comment: Seems you are missing forward slashes before `$post['something']` variables. I.e. `<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['mjesto_polaska']);?>`

Comment: Have you changed routes or you are trying to access to origin routes (class/method/arg)?

Comment: Yeah I configure in router.php

Comment: Can't tell more without seeing those routes. Has adding slashes helped?

Comment: I tryed everythng, adding slashes, configure in routes but nothing helps me

Comment: Ok. Add `routes.php` in question.

Comment: I added,you can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143766/discussion-between-tpojka-and-xerror).

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in files. You can check and let me know if it is working there. Don't forget to load `url` and `form` helpers in config autoload file since you are using some in model too (url_title). Also fill constructor method in controller too.

routes.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
// default routes should be at first place
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['posts']='posts/index/$1';
$route['posts/create']='posts/create';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

index.php view file

```
<h2><?= $title?></h2>
<?php foreach($posts as $post) :?>

<h3><?php echo  $post['mjesto_polaska']; ?></h3>
<small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?>
</small><br>
<br>
<p><a class="btn btn-default"    href="<?php echo 
site_url('/posts/'.$post['mjesto_polaska']);?>">Read More</a></p>
<p><a class="btn btn-default"    href="<?php echo 
site_url('/posts/delete/'.$post['id']);?>">Delete</a></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

view.php view file

```
<h2><?php echo $posts['title'];?></h2>
<small class="post-date">Posted on:<?php echo post['created_at'];?>
</small>
<div class="post-body">
<?php echo $post['body'];?>
</div>
<hr>
<?php form_open('/posts/delete/'.$post['id']);?>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

Comment: I get this type of error

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: title
Filename: posts/index.php
Line Number: 1
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\application\views\posts\index.php
Line: 1
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\application\controllers\Posts.php
Line: 13
Function: view
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: I think the problem is 'title'
Because in my db I don't have this type of field
And I call title here which I don't know why I put title here
I my db I have data: id, mjesto_polaska, mjesto_odredista, datum_polaska, datum_povratka, cijena, broj_mjesta, opis,created_at

Comment: I am trying to help. :) Can you explain bit more detailed? What have you got as error message?

Comment: Call to undefined function open_form() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\application\views\posts\view.php on line 3
Call to undefined function open_form() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\application\views\posts\view.php on line 3

here is output of error message

Comment: The problem is view.php. I have to generate a view that I can see all detail about a trip. I found a error :) :D 
But have no idea how to do that, because I am totalyy noob with PHP CodeIgniter

Comment: Actually, [function name](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open) is `form_open()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143786/discussion-between-xerror-and-tpojka).

Comment: In `APPPATH.'config/autoload.php'` file (i.e. `C:\xampp\htdocs\CS\application\config\autoload.php`) in helpers section set `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');`

Comment: I did this part